# Unit test cases for SampleDaoImpl using Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, jdbctemplate

I have this:

```
public class SimpleDaoImpl implements SimpleDao{ 
    public boolean isAttributeAlreadyExists(Attribute attribute){
        boolean exists = false;
        String query = "SELECT count(*) from ATTRIBUTE WHERE ATTRIBUTE_NAME = ? AND DISPLAY_NAME = ?";
        Integer count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{attribute.getName(), attribute.getDisplayName()}, Integer.class);
        if(null != count && count > 0) {
            exists = true;
        }
        return exists;
     }
```

And test class:

```
public class SimpleDaoImplTest{
    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private SimpleDaoImpl attributeDaoImpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testIsAttributeAlreadyExists(){
        Attribute attribute = getAttribute();
        attributeDaoImpl.isAttributeAlreadyExists(attribute);
        doReturn(true).when(attributeDaoImpl).isAttributeAlreadyExists(attribute);
        assertTrue(attributeDaoImpl.isAttributeAlreadyExists(attribute));
    }

    public Attribute getAttribute(){
        return new Attribute(attributeName, displayName);
    }
```

So my goal is:

1) to test if I implemented unit test case correctly using JUnit/Mockito.

2) when I "Run with coverage" in IntelliJ IDE class is not fully covered(class coverage is not 100%) and only when I add `attributeDaoImpl.isAttributeAlreadyExists(attribute);` before doReturn method it turns green(means class covered 100%), why so?

3) even after that, IDE shows me that  `exists = true;` line inside null & count check is not covered, I am trying to call that line but no luck so far, how I can execute it?

Comment: `2)` - if you mock the method, it isn't called, hence its not covered.

Comment: `3)` -  you need to define behaviour for the `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` to return something that is not null

Comment: @second thanks for reply! Overall, do you think I am doing it right? Should I add more testing?

Comment: In general you want to avoid mocking or spying the class you test. Your example does not show a reason why you should spy on it. If you have two tests (one where `queryForObject` returns null and one where it does not) you have full path coverage with should be sufficient. -- On another note, you are probably required to have a `Integration Test` for this (against a real database). Which would make this unit tests superfluous.